# But it still error application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission

Tags: android, permissions

I follow : [Android INJECT_EVENTS permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383401/android-inject-events-permission)
and [Permission: INJECT_EVENTS for Instrumenation to other apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410903/permission-inject-events-for-instrumenation-to-other-apps)

1.I have done root my phone success.

2.I have done follow [sign application APK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpxM0ffAvok) and copy `app.apk` to `system/app` and set permission `app.apk` to `rw-r--r--` by app root explorer

3.I add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS" />` in Androidmanifest.xml

but It still error require inject permissoin. I don't know why?

```
    06-06 21:23:31.815: E/OpenCV::camera(21812): calling (*pGetPropertyC)(0x7bde06c8, 3)
06-06 21:23:32.058: E/AndroidRuntime(21812): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1881
06-06 21:23:32.058: E/AndroidRuntime(21812): Process: com.example.handtracking, PID: 21812
06-06 21:23:32.058: E/AndroidRuntime(21812): java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
06-06 21:23:32.058: E/AndroidRuntime(21812):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
06-06 21:23:32.058: E/AndroidRuntime(21812):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
06-06 21:23:32.058: E/AndroidRuntime(21812):    at android.hardware.input.IInputManager$Stub$Proxy.injectInputEvent(IInputManager.java:356)
06-06 21:23:32.058: E/AndroidRuntime(21812):    at android.hardware.input.InputManager.injectInputEvent(InputManager.java:642)
06-06 21:23:32.058: E/AndroidRuntime(21812):    at android.app.Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(Instrumentation.java:937)
06-06 21:23:32.058: E/AndroidRuntime(21812):    at com.example.handtracking.CameraService$CameraWorker$2.run(CameraService.java:293)
06-06 21:23:32.274: E/Surface(240): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
06-06 21:23:32.276: E/MtkCam/DisplayClient(240): (22102)[enquePrvOps] mpStreamOps->enqueue_buffer failed: status[Broken pipe(32)], rpImgBuf(0xb7381fb8,0xaeeb1000) (enquePrvOps){#369:mediatek/hardware/mtkcam/v1/client/DisplayClient/DisplayClient.Stream.cpp}
06-06 21:23:32.406: E/Sensors(785): handleToDriver handle(0)
06-06 21:23:32.406: E/Sensors(785): handleToDriver handle(0)
06-06 21:23:32.409: E/Sensors(785): new setDelay handle(0),ns(1000000)m, error(0), index(1)
06-06 21:23:32.409: E/Accel(785): ACC batch: handle:0, en:0, maxBatchReportLatencyNs:0 
06-06 21:23:32.409: E/Sensors(785): sensor 0 go to common batch
06-06 21:23:32.480: E/Sensors(785): handleToDriver handle(0)
06-06 21:23:32.480: E/Sensors(785): handleToDriver handle(0)
06-06 21:23:32.483: E/Sensors(785): new setDelay handle(0),ns(1000000)m, error(0), index(1)
06-06 21:23:32.483: E/Accel(785): ACC batch: handle:0, en:0, maxBatchReportLatencyNs:0 
06-06 21:23:32.483: E/Sensors(785): sensor 0 go to common batch
06-06 21:23:32.743: E/PROXIMITY(785): ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
06-06 21:23:32.843: E/PROXIMITY(785): ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
06-06 21:23:33.543: E/PROXIMITY(785): ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
```

Code Inject event

```
thread_touch = new Thread(){
                       @Override
                       public void run(){
                               Instrumentation m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();

                               m_Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(
                                       SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                                       SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                                       MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,x, y, 0));
                               m_Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(
                                       SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                                       SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                                       MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,x,y, 0));
                       }
                   };
                   thread_touch.start();
```

My phone is Lenovo P70 android 4.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This permission is granted to system apps. 3rd party cannot have it. Unless you sign your app with system certificate, you will not be granted `INJECT_EVENTS` permission.

[Docs here read](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INJECT_EVENTS):

> Allows an application to inject user events (keys, touch, trackball)
>   into the event stream and deliver them to ANY window. Without this
>   permission, you can only deliver events to windows in your own
>   process.
>
> **Not for use by third-party applications**.

Comment: How to sign my app with system certificate? Can you give me link .

Comment: As with any other. But you have to have system certificate first and this is not a public thing.

Comment: How can I to have system certificate in my app?

Comment: This is something I would like to know as well, do even CyanogenMod sources provide a system certificate file or is it behind the original developers?

Comment: You cannot have system certificate unless you are building whole system image yourself and which means you need to create own certificate to become system one. .

Comment: I have own system.img from my phone. Can I change my app and system.img to Compatibility.